# jQuery $.post affecting multiple rows in table after a previous accidental click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a web page that allows authorized users to update or delete rows in a MySQL table. The table has the columns `id` (INT), `label` (VARCHAR), `details` (VARCHAR), `templateId` (INT), and `auditable` (TINYINT, either 0 or 1). This table is displayed as HTML on the front end, with "Label", "Details", "Auditable?" and "Edit/Delete" columns showing.

Clicking the "Edit" button on a row, changing some data in the resulting Bootstrap modal form, and clicking "Save Changes" works fine. The problem occurs when I click "Edit", click "Cancel" on the form, and then click another row (say, for example, I accidentally clicked the wrong row). When I click the button to execute the edit on that newly clicked row, both that row and the initially clicked row will be affected. The Chrome console shows that two JavaScript objects are being sent via `$.post()`, though I cannot figure out why from the logic I wrote (see below). I looked in MySQL and the duplicate results are there, confirming the page accurately reflects the update. Is there some `$.get` or `$.post` cache behavior in jQuery I am not aware of? (This also occurs with the delete functionality, but I'm limiting the question for brevity's sake).

Main page (GUI):

```
// The 'edit this row' button that brings up the modal form
$(".edit-action").click(function() {

  // Clear any previously set values in form
  $("#editActionLabel").val('');
  $("#editActionDetails").val('');
  $(".radio-edit-action").prop("checked", false);

  // All edit button id's in GUI table will be "edit-action-[`id` in database]" 
  // Grab number out of there and convert from string to number
  var actionId = $(this).attr("id");
  actionId = parseInt(actionId.slice(12));

  // Grab data from database to populate fields
  $.get("data.php?a=actionData&actionId=" + actionId, function(d) {

    // Returning a JSON encoded array isn't working, 
    // so I'm sending back a comma-separated string instead 
    var response = d.split(",");
    var label = response[0];
    var details = response[1];
    var auditable = parseInt(response[2]);

    $("#editActionLabel").val(label);
    $("#editActionDetails").val(details);

    if (auditable == 1) {
      $("#editAuditableNo").prop("checked", false);
      $("#editAuditableYes").prop("checked", true);
    } else if (auditable == 0) {
      $("#editAuditableYes").prop("checked", false);
      $("#editAuditableNo").prop("checked", true);
    }

    // Only reset `auditable` variable if selection was changed
    $(".radio-edit-action").change(function() {
      auditable = $(this).val();
      auditable = parseInt(auditable);
    });

    // User clicks "Save Changes" instead of "Cancel"
    $("#executeEdit").click(function() {

      var label = $("#editActionLabel").val();
      var details = $("#editActionDetails").val();

      var obj = {
        "operation": "edit",
        "actionId": actionId,
        "label": label,
        "details": details,
        "auditable": auditable
      };

      console.log("The object passed to 'edit' this row:");
      console.log(obj);

      $.post("data.php", obj, function(r) {
        // Confirm success or failure to user
        $("#crudResult").html(r);
      });
    }); // end click

  });

}); // end 'edit action'
```

data.php (called via AJAX to execute the UPDATE in database. Only relevant code shown):

```
$debug = false;

$operation      =   $_POST['operation'];
$action_id      =   (isset($_POST['actionId'])      ?   $_POST['actionId']    : '');         
$label          =   (isset($_POST['label'])         ?   $_POST['label']       : 'NULL');
$details        =   (isset($_POST['details'])       ?   $_POST['details']     : 'NULL');
$auditable      =   (isset($_POST['auditable'])     ?   $_POST['auditable']   : 'NULL');  

switch ($operation) {

    case 'edit':

        $query = "
            UPDATE actions 
            SET label='$label', 
                details='$details', 
                auditable=$auditable
            WHERE id=$action_id 
            LIMIT 1";

        // DB connection not shown. Yes, I know I should be using PDO...
        $result = mysqli_query($db_conn, $query);

        // PHP echoes out the result; let the calling JavaScript figure out where to place it
        if ($result) {
            echo '<p class="text-success">Action successfully updated!</p>';
        } else {
            echo '<p class="text-warning">There was an error and the action could not be edited.</p>';
            // Don't show error to user in production, when $debug should be false
            if ($debug) {
                echo '<p><b>Error:</b> ' . mysqli_error($db_conn) . '</p>';
            }
        }

        break;

    /* case 'delete': ... */

}
```

The modal form, which follows Bootstrap's template HTML, is simply a collection of fields and a couple buttons (no `<form>` wrapped around it). Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: I would be suspicious of the click event handler that is bound inside your get request callback. If that element never gets replaced then you are binding compounded events to it. Try delegating that event instead (if element gets replaced any time) or leave it as a direct binding but defintiely move it out of the callback

Comment: I moved the "save" click outside the "edit" click, and just needed to make `actionId` into a global variable so it was available to the "save" click. It's working now. If you have any suggestions on how to avoid global variables here, I'm all ears. In any case, thank you.

Comment: can pass the data to the the other button using jQuery `data()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many times is the request to server occurs? I Bet it is twice.
The problem is on the client side.
For each edit click you have made, a new save click function has been created.
You do not need to add this for every edit click, take it out from the edit click function.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That worked (as I also said in my comment to charlietfl above), so I've accepted your answer. Thank you.